# rollback in oracle10g (nunit unittesting)

Tags: c#, oracle, nunit, oracle10g

i am doing unittesting in connecting to oracle database,
i wanted to achieve rollback after the testcase,

I am having express edition of oracle 10g,

I tried xtUnit(Datarollback attribute does not works for me),Flashback(it works in enterprise edition only)

is there any other way to achieve this...

Please help me

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have any DDL in your testcase, it will cause an implicit commit. Just a rollback will not help in that case.

Comment: yes... i want some other solution to rollback in these cases.. is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

with NUnit you can define methods that will be run before and after each test.  In the before method, create a transaction to the oracle database.  In the after method, abort the transaction.